# How do I target next div that's not a sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add a `current-month` and a `next-month` class to some divs. The plan is to use jquery to target the first one and the second one. Once I interact with the current month I'll switch the `next-month` to `current-month` and add `next-month` to the next target div.

I'm targeting the first one fine but can't seem to target the next:

```
$('.event-month-container').first().addClass("current-month");
$('.event-month-container.current-month').next(".event-month-container").addClass("current-month");
```

code as I'm using it -> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FuMV4/)

----- edit -----
The end result is:

Onload the first div is tagged as the `current-month` and the second is tagged as the `next-month`. When the `current-month` reaches the top of the screen I'm going to set it to a fixed position. When the `next-month` reaches the bottom of the current month it will push the current month out of the way, remove the `current-month` class and add it to the `next-month` and add `next-month` to the third month and so on...

----- edit v2 -----

html

```
<div id="boxes">
        <div class="box quadruple">
            <div class="event-month-container">
                <p>June 2014</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box single event">
            .... event info ....
        </div>
     ......

        <div class="box quadruple">
            <div class="event-month-container">
                <p>July 2014</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box single event">
            ...event info...
        </div>
     ......
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.event-month-container').first().addClass("current-month");
$('.event-month-container.current-month').next(".event-month-container").addClass("current-month");
```

I need to target the first `event-month-container` in the `quadruple` div and the next `event-month-container` in a different `quadruple` div. At a specific scroll point I'll switch what is my current and target the next `event-month-container` after that.

Comment: I've had two votes to close this. Why?

Comment: Because it's conceptual and not really any code for anyone to help with.

Comment: That's why I provided a jsfiddle

Comment: The code present in the question should be enough for users to answer said question without having to go to jsFiddle. And the example should demonstrate the problem in its most minimalistic form, not a wall of code.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using these selectors instead :

```
var $current = $('.event-month-container').first();
$current.addClass('current-month');

var $next = $current.parent().siblings('.box.quadruple').find('.event-month-container');
$next.addClass('next-month');
```

It's all about proper DOM Tree Traversal.

Comment: that never adds the `next-month` class to the next month div

Comment: @dcp3450 sorry, use `.siblings()` instead of `.next()` -- check edit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what the workflow is, but if you just need to get the first one, work with it, move to the next one, etc, you could use `eq` to move by index, like so:

```
$('.event-month-container').eq(0).addClass("current-month");
// do something, move on
$('.event-month-container').eq(1).addClass("current-month");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.event').click(
function() {
    $(this).removeClass("current");
    $(this).next().addClass("current");
}
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FuMV4/1/

something like this might help? I am not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: nothing is done on click. The classes are added to the first and second items on load. As I scroll when these classes reach a certain point the current will be switched to the next and the next after that one will get the `next` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've over-complicated it. Month's are already "ID'd" in a way that you easily figure out the next one given the current one. E.g. Current:"2014-04" => Next:"2014-05". Just make a quick one-line function to calculate the next ID given the current one and pass this into your selector.

Comment: If the next month doesn't have an event then it won't fall in order.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach in which there is a counter that runs through the total number of elements to which you want to add a class.

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PR49J/) is rudimentary in that it just shifts a "thisdiv" "nextdiv" down a row of divs just like a shift-register, and the counter is reset when you get to the end.

A problem will arise if you are shifting by formal dates, you'll have to use the javascript date function so it will shift to the appropriate "first of the month" based on the last month (e.g., Feb with 28 days March 1 next, June 30 days July 1 is next).

JS

```
var thisdiv=0;
var nextdiv=1;
console.log('---------------------');

$('#clickme').on('click', function(){
    console.log(thisdiv, nextdiv);
    addmovement(thisdiv, nextdiv);
    if(thisdiv == 4)
    {
     thisdiv = -1;
     }
    if(nextdiv == 4)
    {
     nextdiv = -1;
       }
    ++thisdiv;
    ++nextdiv;
});

function addmovement( thisdiv, nextdiv )
{
    $('div').removeClass('thisdiv');
    $('div').removeClass('nextdiv');
    $('div:eq('+ thisdiv +')').addClass('thisdiv');
    $('div:eq('+ nextdiv +')').addClass('nextdiv');  
}
```